# Azure Functions TypeScript debug (f5) not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, npm, azure-functions

Not able to run my Azure function (TypeScript) locally in VS code.
I get the following errors as attached. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open `Terminal => Navigate to root directory of your project`, run the below commands to `uninstall Azure function core tools and reinstall` again:

```
npm uninstall -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools --unsafe-perm true
```

[image]

3. Delete the  `node_modules`  and `package-lock.json` folders in your project directory.
4. Run the following command to reinstall all the packages:

   ```
   1. npm install 
   2. npm start
   ```

[image]

- Packages gets reinstalled.

5. Rebuild the project and try debugging or deploying it again.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting the error in Azure portal after deployed. you can get the code at - I am able to run it and deployed to azure too. But in Azure I get the following error: Worker was unable to load function Cannot find module '@azure/storage-blob' Require stack: - C:\home\site\wwwroot\dist\AnchorImageFileProcessor\index.js - C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.26.1\workers\node\dist\src\worker-bundle.js - C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.26.1\workers\node\dist\src\nodejsWorker.js' SC:: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qiEatsaMkYm8GeP0RyHg5LiR130UWg4S/view

Comment: `you can get the code at - ` Can you please share your code(if available in GitHub, share repo link).